# Как получить список ревизий по сообщению в SVN

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

Подскажите, возможно ли получить список ревизий, которым соответствует заданное сообщение при commit?

Comment: `svn log | findstr "фрагмент комментария"` не сгодится?

Comment: @dunduk, вряд ли, потому что ты предлагаешь фильтрацию вывода, соответственно будут проверены только те коммиты, которые были сделаны недавно. svn log же не выводит полную историю коммитов за всё время? А даже если его можно заставить это сделать, то это будет выполняться долго.

Comment: Так в мане по tortiosesvn явно пишут, что его гуй тем более может не справится с просмотром большого количества коммитов (раздел 4, глава "Диалоговое окно журнала ревизий"). А фильтра по комментариям там просто нет вроде бы, только сортировка.

Comment: А, вот же, из мана по `svn log`:  --search ARG
Filters log messages to show only those that match the search pattern ARG. Log messages are displayed only if the provided search pattern matches **any of the author, date, log message text**.

Comment: @dunduk ну так запостите это как ответ, а не как комментарий

Comment: Я не такой знаток tortoise, чтобы утверждать про отсутствие фильтрации у него в гуе на 100%. По беглому взгляду на документацию вроде нет, но мало ли. Получится ответ не на тот вопрос, если всё-таки есть :)

Comment: @dunduk, всё равно в ответы про search.

Comment: `svn log | findstr "фрагмент комментария"` - в принципе эта конструкция ищет, но мне бы получить список ревизий, а находится просто совпадающий текст. Без автора, без номера ревизии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо, [dunduk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183549/dunduk) конструкция `svn log http://my.svn.ru/trunk --search 13680` полностью подходит.
Ищет в репозитории `http://my.svn.ru/trunk` все упоминания слова `13680` и выводит их в таком вот виде:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r11050 | author      | 2015-04-27 14:04:01 +0400 (Пн, 27 апр 2015) | 1 line

http://url/13680
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r11049 | author      | 2015-04-24 22:14:15 +0400 (Пт, 24 апр 2015) | 1 line

http://url/13680
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r11048 | author      | 2015-04-24 22:11:34 +0400 (Пт, 24 апр 2015) | 1 line

http://url/13680
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

```
svn log | grep "фрагмент" -C 3
```

grep можно настроить сколько строк показывать до и после найденой строки
это команда для командной строки Linux.

```
-B, --before-context=ЧИС  печатать ЧИСЛО строк предшествующего контекста
-A, --after-context=ЧИС   печатать ЧИСЛО строк последующего контекста
-C, --context[=ЧИС]       печатать ЧИСЛО строк контекста
```

Comment: 1) под windows нет grep (что windows - следует из тегов) 2) см. ключ `--search`

Comment: В теме не указана платформа. В тэгах присутствует svn, я выдал вариант. Как в tortoise-svn это сделать незнаю.

Comment: Tortoise-svn в тегах - это windows, без вариантов :)

Comment: Ну малоли, может консоль не осилил сидит под вайном. )))

Comment: В windows'е есть findstr начиная с семёрки точно, а возможно с висты.

Comment: Используемая платформа - Windows 7.